# amcl restore own position automatically

Tags: ros, navigation, pose, estimation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sometime AMCL can't localize itself in the given map while moving. such as in alike environments. In similar cases I use pose estimation button for real position of robot.

But is there a way to detect automatically that AMCL get lost real robot position ?

EXAMPLE:  a node give me an error " ROBOT CAN'NOT LOCALIZE ITSELF" . after AMCL will try immediately localize right position. So, I dont use pose estimation button .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226760/amcl-restore-own-position-automatically/) by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-02-16**:
not sure what you would hope to do in that situation - If the robot can't localise itself, what would amcl be able to do. The pose estimation tool is you providing additional information that is not available to the system to enable it to hopefully converge on a suitable answer

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2016-02-16**:
just ı want to detect that robot get lost very much its real position with a another node. not look at rviz screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you could look at the topics you get from amcl - amcl_pose gives you pose with covariance, or you could look at particlecloud to see how spread out it is (this is what rviz is using to draw things).

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osmancns](https://answers.ros.org/users/22439/osmancns/) on 2016-02-17**:
is there a example project about this. so it can detect position errors as look at topics me get from amcl-pose ?